# HQL: Two conditions in where clause returning empty result

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hql

I am trying to select from db using HQL with two conditions as below:

```
String hql = "from User u where u.login=? and u.password=?";
Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql);
System.out.println(query);
query.setString(0, u);
query.setString(1, p);
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<User> listUser = (List<User>) query.list();
System.out.println(listUser);
if (listUser != null && !listUser.isEmpty()) {
    return true;
}

return false;
```

But I am getting empty result. I tried by giving only one condition , then it is giving proper result. (i.e. from User u where u.login=?). How to achieve this with two conditions?

Comment: Does it work when you only pass the password as a parameter ? If not how are you storing your passwords in your database ?

Comment: Yeah it is working when I pass only password. Either of them is working but not both.

Comment: Ok, then I'm sorry to say that I don't know. I tried the same on my db with some user and it's working fine. Hope someone else can help you out on this.

Comment: I solved this issue . Thanks all

Comment: What was the problem ?